# Why is this expression considered immutable, and therefore can be defined using `val`?

Tags: kotlin, immutability, accessor

In a training video, I saw a nice, concise "trick" to demonstrate accessors that looked like this:

```
val alive
    get() = health > 0
```

This provided a nice, easy way to provide a "getter and setter" all in one, where the "setter" is really just a derived value.  I understand all that.

But I guess I don't *quite* understand what `val` means, and therefore "immutable" means.  I was imagining a location in memory that was unchangeable. Is that really what's happening here?  Maybe the location in memory actually points to an expression that is expecting a value (health), and so therefore this is, in effect, immutable.

Comment: That doesn't have a setter, it's immutable because it's getter (i.e. read) only. It's also not a trick, it's just how you do it: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to think of `val` as *read-only* rather than *immutable*.

Also, please note that you're not declaring the **expression** as `val`, but the **property**.

Declaring a `val` property will only generate a getter for the property, not a setter. In Java, you could have written the same "computed getter" (without a backing field, and without a setter):

```java
public class Player {
    private int health = 100;

    public int getHealth() { 
        return health; 
    }

    public void setHealth(int health) { 
        this.health = health; 
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return health > 0;
    }
}
```

> I was imagining a location in memory that was unchangeable.

As you can see in the Java equivalent above, it's not even a location in memory (there is no backing field). Each time the property is accessed (internally using the generated getter), the expression health > 0 is evaluated again and may yield a different value than a previous access to the property.

Comment: Thanks!  So, just to confirm, I am declaring the object `alive` as `val` (`alive` is a property). Then `alive` can have the values of either `true` or `false`, and in fact **those values can change**, but that is OK because `val` does not mean immutable, just not *directly mutable*. (Its state can change only via the resolution of the expression `health > 0`.)  Is that right?

Comment: @MikeWilliamson yes, that's correct. `val` just means no one can directly set the value of the `alive` property (no setter). Each time the property is accessed (internally using the generated getter) the expression `health > 0` is evaluated again and may yield a different value than a previous access to the property.